# Which activity/program prevents my monitor from going off?

Tags: x11, xorg, kde, dpms

I can set my monitor off with `xset dpms force off` but something prevents KDE from setting it off. On the other hand, when I play a long youtube video it might go off (!). This correctly happens after 5 minutes, as I have already set in "System Settings > Power Management > Energy Saving > (checked) Screen Energy Saving > Switch off after 5 min".

How to check which activity/program is preventing my monitor from going off?

Comment: Perhaps VLC, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440321/when-using-vlc-why-does-my-screen-saver-keep-waking-up